# Is it possible to make, Google Spread Sheet as a database, replacement to oracle/mySql/Sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, oracle, google-sheets

Is it possible to make, Google Spread Sheet as a database, replacement to oracle/mySql/Sql ?

Like we can directly connect the spread sheet and make multiple sub sheets as tables and sheet as the DB-Name, do any one know some thing about this?

Comment: Yes, in the same way it's possible to use swallows to transport coconuts.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use it as a replacement to Oracle/MySQL/SQL. It is possible to store data but will slow down the app. Using a Database like Oracle/MySQL/SQL is better. MySQL is always free. Try that.

[Can I make Google Drive Spreadsheets act like a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985837/can-i-make-google-drive-spreadsheets-act-like-a-mysql-database)

Comment: But for apps, like basic catalogs system, where just CMS is connected and we can get that data into mobile app just for display of data.

That can actually minimize the cost of server. 

But the main point is it technically feasible ?

Comment: Yup. I see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985837/can-i-make-google-drive-spreadsheets-act-like-a-mysql-database this link has the answer for that